# Action that does not delete even if swiped with a finger when in List?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Since NavigationView has been deprecated since iOS16 in SwiftUI, instead use NavigationStack instead, which was effective at NavigationView, does not delete even if swiped with a finger when List, Enable delete function only in edit mode code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = ["first", "second", "twenty"]
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(array, id: \.self) { array in
                    Text(array)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: editMode.isEditing ? rowRemove : nil)
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
    
    func rowRemove(offsets: IndexSet) {
        array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

When I rewritten it to NavigationStack and executed it, it was deleted even though it was not in edit mode.
 How should I use NavigationStack to achieve a similar "action that does not delete even if swiped with a finger when in List"?

Comment: Could you show the code with NavigationStack ?

Comment: without major changes,

`var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {`

However,` .onDelete` does not work as it is, so I changed it, but if this` .onDelete `exists, I can swipe to delete, so I would like to somehow stop the swipe.

Comment: According to Apple this appears to be a bug. I will wait until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple this appears to be a bug. I will wait until it is fixed.